# oscillation identity proof

Tags: real-analysis

$$Let\,f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\,be\,bounded\,and\,E\subset\mathbb{R}.\:The\:quantity\:
\omega(f, E) = \sup_{x,y \in E}\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert\:
is\:called\:oscillation\:of\:f\:on\:E$$
$$
Proposition: \omega(f, E) = \sup_{x \in E}f(x) - \inf_{x \in E}f(x)$$
Proof: $$ \forall x,y \in E \:f(x)\leqslant \sup_{x \in E} f(x)\land f(y) \geqslant \inf_{x \in E} f(x) \Rightarrow\\
\forall x,y \in E \:f(x) - f(y) \leqslant \sup_{x \in E}(f(x)) - \inf_{x \in E}f(x)\land f(y) - f(x) \leqslant \sup_{x \in E}f(x) - \inf_{x \in E}f(x)\Rightarrow\\
\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \leqslant \sup_{x \in E} f(x) - \inf_{x \in E} f(x) \Rightarrow\\
\omega(f, E) \leqslant \sup_{x \in E} f(x) - \inf_{x \in E} f(x) \\
...
$$

I dont understand why last implication is true, we proved for all x, y in E but not for supremum.

Comment: The supremum is the smallest of the upper bounds, and you found an upper bound...

Comment: @JulioPuerta well thats embarrassing, i guess i got lost in symbols and forgot about basics.